# window.addEventListener('scroll', func) triggers after window.location="#target"

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a button on a page. When I click the button, the page scrolls down to the specified target and then adds an event listener `window` for the `scroll` event, however the scroll event gets triggered immediately rather than the next time a user scrolls.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how I can add a scroll event to `window` after it scrolls to a specified target? I'm using Firefox 37.0.2

**HTML**

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
<!-- Enough br tags to make the page have a scroll bar -->
<div id="target">Text</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Both of the following will trigger the scroll event:

    //window.location = '#target';
    //document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView();

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        // Removes this function from the window's onscroll event so that it only triggers once
        this.removeEventListener('scroll', arguments.callee);
        alert('Triggered!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use # navigation. Use scrollintoview or the jquery plugin navigation, which also supports callback (run after scroll finishes) that would solve your issue. Also, in my opinion, you should specify what browsers you are targeting.
tl;dr: You are describing normal browser behavior. which you can avoid by ordering the events properly.

Comment: @TigOldBitties I have the same problem with both # navigation and `scrollIntoView()`. Doesn't scrolling the page before adding the onscroll event count as ordering my events properly? Also, I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: As far as i can tell from your description, adding the event listener does not wait for the scroll to finish. That's what i mean by proper ordering. Make sure it's added after it scrolls.

Comment: @TigOldBitties I don't know how to do that. That's the whole point of this question. Do I add a time delay or something? Is there some way to tell when the browser is done scrolling?

Comment: You either recreate the scrollintoview plugin (which is a lot of work), that adds a callback for the complete, or use the plugin and make use of the "complete" parameter, that lets you run your code after scroll completes. No other solution imo.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/degana/7/edit
Mocked up a working demo of what I think you mean
You might need to hit "run js" button before it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the comments, it seems that the problem is caused by browsers not scrolling immediately. I was able to solve this with a simple `setTimeout` to delay `addEventListener` by 1ms.

My revised code is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Both of the following will work now:

    //window.location = '#target';
    //document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView();

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            // Removes this function from the window's onscroll event so that it only triggers once
            this.removeEventListener('scroll', arguments.callee);
            alert('Triggered!');
        });
    }, 1);
});
```